# How to nicely annotate a ggplot2 (manual)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `ggplot2` I normally use `geom_text` and something like `position=jitter` to annotate my plots.

However - for a nice plot I often finds it worthwhile to annotate manually. like below:

```
data2 <- structure(list(type = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("EDS", 
"KIU", "LAK", "MVH", "NA*"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.9, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.09, 0, 0.8, 0.05, 0, 0.15, 0, 0.41, 0.04, 0.03, 
0.52, 0, 0.23, 0.11, 0.02, 0.64, 0.01), time = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L), year = c(2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L)), .Names = c("type", "value", 
"time", "year"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), class = "data.frame")
ggplot(data2, aes(x=time, y=value, group=type, col=type))+
geom_line()+
geom_point()+
theme_bw()+
annotate("text", x=6, y=0.9, label="this is a wrong color")+
annotate("text", x=15, y=0.6, label="this is a second annotation with a wrong color")
```

The problem is, that I can't get the text annotations color to match the line color. I assume I could fix this with a manual scale, but I hope there is a better way?

Comment: see also the `directlabels` package

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you use geom_text() instead of annotate() you can pass a group color to your plot:

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x=time, y=value, group=type, col=type))+
geom_line()+
geom_point()+
theme_bw() +
geom_text(aes(7, .9, label="correct color", color="NA*")) +
geom_text(aes(15, .6, label="another correct color!", color="MVH"))
```

So using annotate() it looks like this:
[alt text http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/before.png](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/before.png)

then after using geom_text() it looks like this:
[alt text http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/after.png](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/after.png)

Comment: Did you notice the legend on the right side? Normally it should be a circle instead of an 'a' on the line. This does not look good.

Comment: I am also getting the label. Anyway to remove this?

Comment: You can get rid of the 'a' by adding "show_guide = F" to geom_text. (The answer by mbask prevents ugly rendering by duplication and should be used instead. Also there the show_guide option should be set to F.)

Answer (score 66):

I had a similar problem and solved it with JD Long answer. But as a results of `ggplot2` updating to version 0.9.0 I noticed that all `geom_text()`calls rendered somewhat blurred on the plots.

Thanks to [kohske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314020/kohske) I discovered that this code

```
ggplot(data2, aes(x=time, y=value, group=type, col=type))+
geom_line()+
geom_point()+
theme_bw() +
geom_text(aes(7, .9, label="correct color", color="NA*")) +
geom_text(aes(15, .6, label="another correct color!", color="MVH"))
```

plots the geom_text `nrow(data2)`times!

The correct way for supplying data to geom_text is building a different data.frame holding coordinates, labels and colors for the strings you want to be plotted:

```
data2.labels <- data.frame(
  time = c(7, 15), 
  value = c(.9, .6), 
  label = c("correct color", "another correct color!"), 
  type = c("NA*", "MVH")
  )

ggplot(data2, aes(x=time, y=value, group=type, col=type))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw() +
  geom_text(data = data2.labels, aes(x = time, y = value, label = label))
```

Comment: This is a much better answer, especially for large data sets. The geom_text duplication can really kill a PDF, makes rendering it painfully slow.

Comment: Ran into the same problem and this solved it! Using geom_text() without its own data mapping will result in overplotting and poor resolution of the text. Providing a data mapping will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @kohske and @mbask.  For those getting "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" errors when using code above. Try when making your dataframe to include option `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: use `check_overlap = TRUE` and it is only rendered once :)

Comment: That's correct @shil88. Since ggplot 2.0.0 ([released](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v2.0.0) 2015/12/18): "`check_overlap = TRUE` provides a simple way to avoid overplotting
of labels: labels that would otherwise overlap are omitted"

Answer (score 0):

These days there are packages adding labeling:

1. geom_dl from the directlabel package with automatic data filtering to avoid repeated labels and
2. geom_label_repel and geom_text_repel from package ggrepel make labels that try to avoid sitting on top of the data or each other and which in the case of geom_label_repel have a boundary and a non-transparant background.