# How to make ggplot2 plots prettier?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have generated the following plot using the R code that follows it:
[image]

```
ggplot(lengths, aes(length, fill = library)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 60000))
```

Now I would like to make the plot a bit prettier:

1. Make the x-axis show length every
   5000 units (instead of every 20000)
2. Add x-values on top of the three
       peaks (approx 3000,5000 and 35000).

How can I do that?

**update**
in response to James:
[image]

Comment: FWIW, that's a pretty sexy plot right there.

Comment: You could add a vertical line from the peaks to the x-axis.  `geom_segment(data = peakdat, aes(x=x, xend=x, y=y, yend=0))` should to the trick, where `peakdat` is from Ben B's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

(first create a reproducible example)

```
set.seed(1001)
lengths <- data.frame(length=c(rgamma(1000,shape=10,scale=500),
                    10000+rgamma(1000,shape=5,scale=700),
                    rnorm(500,mean=30000,sd=2000)),
                  library=factor(rep(2:1,c(2000,500))))
```

(cute stuff to find peak locations and heights)

```
peakfun <- function(x) {
  d <- density(x$length)
  peaks <- which(diff(sign(diff(d$y)))==-2)
  data.frame(x=d$x[peaks],y=d$y[peaks])
}

peakdat <- ddply(lengths,.(library),peakfun)
peakdat <- peakdat[-1,] ## drop spurious peak
```

(draw the plot)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(lengths, aes(length, fill = library)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,60000),
                     breaks = seq(0,60000,by=5000))+
  geom_text(data=peakdat,aes(x=x,y=y,label=round(x)),vjust=1)
```

you probably want to tweak the vertical height of the labels a little

Answer (score 6):

1: `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=rep(5000,12))`.

You could also put the `xlim` declaration in here, using `limits`, eg,

```
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=rep(5000,12),limits=c(0,60000))
```

2: For the labels you could use `annotate()` or `geom_text()`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409357/how-to-nicely-annotate-a-ggplot2-manual) post for examples. You would have to calculate the values yourself for this though.

Comment: adding the xlim declaration does not seem to work well. see original post to see what I get.

Comment: Sorry, it uses `limits` rather than `xlim` here, edited original post to explain better.